# No icon in button elfinder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have following the instalation on [elfinder](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder)

My code looked like this :

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://192.168.5.223/develop_tsurumaru/assets/admin/css/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://192.168.5.223/develop_tsurumaru/assets/admin/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://192.168.5.223/develop_tsurumaru/assets/admin/css/theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://192.168.5.223/develop_tsurumaru/assets/admin/css/elfinder.min.css">
</head>

<body>

   <div id="elfinder-tag"> </div>


   <script src="http://192.168.5.223/develop_tsurumaru/assets/admin/js/jquery.js">
   <script src="http://192.168.5.223/develop_tsurumaru/assets/admin/js/jquery-ui.min.js">
   <script src="http://192.168.5.223/develop_tsurumaru/assets/admin/js/bootstrap.min.js">
   <script src="http://192.168.5.223/develop_tsurumaru/assets/admin/js/elfinder.min.js">

   <script>
    jQuery('#elfinder-tag').elfinder({
            url: 'http://192.168.5.223/develop_tsurumaru/members/megumi/file_delivery_order/elfinder'
        }).elfinder('instance');

</script>

</body>
```

But gives me a button with no icon like this :

[image: No icons on button]

For any help, it so appreciated

Comment: Inspect one of those buttons and see their CSS rule. Files with icon images must have been misplaced.

Comment: I put img that needed by css elfinder on codeigniter_folder/assets/admin/img/elfinder/ . How can I declare it on css: This is the piece of code : .elfinder-button-icon{ background : url('the url of image')}  ?. Btw, Thanks

Comment: Make sure `url('the url of image')` is accessible from the web.

Comment: it accessible on http://192.168.5.223/develop_tsurumaru/assets/admin/img/elfinder/toolbar.png